# I'm unable add the padding for this kendo dropdown

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-ui

I've been trying to resize the padding of kendo dropdown. I have taken a separate class
and Id too to make proper padding but no result. In the browser too I've tried to
inspect and make some changes there I got when it comes to editor, I copied the code and
put it in the editor which I made changes in the browser end up failing to make proper
padding.

My HTML code :

---

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<kendo-dropdownlist [data]="UsersInfo" value="Count of Users by Month"
  class="usersdropdown" (selectionChange)="onSelectUsersInfo($event)">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
<kendo-dropdownlist [data]="Years" value={{selectedYear}} style="padding: 10px;"
  class="dropdown" (selectionChange)="onSelectYear($event)">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
<kendo-dropdownlist [data]="Months" value={{selectedMonth}}
  class="dropdown" (selectionChange)="onSelectMonth($event)" >
</kendo-dropdownlist>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
<div class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 150px;">Search</div>
</div>
```

---

My CSS code :

---

```
.usersdropdown {
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-color: white;
    border: none;
}

.k-dropdown .k-dropdown-wrap, .k-dropdowntree {
    border-color: white;
    color: #656565;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}

.k-grid-header, .k-header, .k-grid-header-wrap, .k-grouping- 
 header, .k-grouping-header .k-group-indicator, .k-grid td,
.k-grid-footer, .k-grid-footer-wrap, .k-grid-content-locked,
.k-grid-footer-locked, .k-grid-header-locked, .k-filter-row>td,
.k-filter-row>th {
    border-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.btn-btn-danger {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

.k-dropdown .k-dropdown-wrap, .k-dropdowntree .k-dropdown-wrap {
    border-color: white;
    color: #656565;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px !important ;
}
```

---

Comment: Can you post the CSS code you've tried?

Comment: sure. Most of the classes took from the browser and did modifications

Comment: Try to add `::ng-deep` before the css rules that apply to Kendo elements, for instance `::ng-deep .k-dropdown .k-dropdown-wrap, .k-dropdowntree .k-dropdown-wrap`.

Comment: Thank you gentleman That works amazingly well!

Comment: Great! I've added below an answer based on my comment. Please accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your styles aren't affecting the Kendo component's internal styling is View Encapsulation. You can read about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation).

To penetrate this encapsulation, you can use `::ng-deep` before any CSS selector that accesses elements inside the component which you want to style.

In your case, for example:

```
::ng-deep .k-dropdown .k-dropdown-wrap, .k-dropdowntree .k-dropdown-wrap {
    border-color: white;
    color: #656565;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px !important ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be a global change, move your css to the global style sheet.

If you want to have it apply only in your component, I would wrap everything in a separate class and then place it inside ::ng-deep. This way the styles will not affect everything else on your site once you have loaded this component.

```
::ng-deep {
     .my-custom-wrapper-class {
         // your custom styles here
     }
}
```